# Why is my Express server responding with 404 for all files except index.html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webserver

I'm learning Node.js with Express to get a little server running for studying. I'm getting response code 404 for all requests to files linked in my `index.html` file (e.g. the `.css`, `.js`, and image files).

The code I used to send `index.html`:

```
routes.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/clientSide/index.html"));
})
```

If I change the path to the whole folder instead:

```
routes.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/clientSide"));
})
```

I get in my browser the path from my hard drive to the folder, but I still can't view the files that way.

The `clientSide` folder contains `index.html`, `app.js`, `style.css`, and 2 or 3 images, all in the same folder. I can't view any of them.

I changed the filenames and folder name, and checked for capitalization to no avail.

`SOLVED`

I was using `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static/")));`

With `app = express();`

That does not work, but using `routes.use` instead of `app.use`, while `routes = express.Router();`, is what solves that

The end

Comment: As I understand you try to work with static contents. So why you not try to using express.static? Let's say like described there https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_static_files.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code snippet, when you write:

```js
routes.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/clientSide/index.html"));
})
```

You defined a new middleware function for requests to route `/`; that's what `routes.get('/', ...)` does. Assuming your server is running on port 3000, route `/` maps to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`. For exactly that URL, and no other, Express executes your provided function, which replies with the the file `clientSide/index.html`. Thus, when your browser requests `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`, Express responds correctly.

But you've said nothing about the other files, such as `http://127.0.0.1:3000/style.css`, which would be route `/style.css`. You haven't defined any middleware for that route. So Express, not knowing what to do, by default responds with 404 and an error message. Thus, when your browser tries to load `http://127.0.0.1:3000/style.css` while fetching the resources referenced in `index.html`, the stylesheet fails to load.

Your second code snippet doesn't fix anything. It really makes things worse, because `res.sendFile()` can't send folders (how would that even work?) and that generates errors. You still haven't defined routes other than `/`, and now all your files are inaccessible.

To actually solve the problem, you could, theoretically, tediously define a route for every file, or more cleverly define one route with a [route parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters). But serving a static folder with Express is a solved problem. You can simply offload the work to [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) by replacing all your code with:

```js
routes.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "clientSide/")));
```

To go even further, you don't need Express or Node.js for a static file server. Try [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/). And for simple webpages, you don't need a server at all; just double-click `index.html` and let your browser open it.

Comment: Yeah, its the second time i try doing the whole folder static. With that i get "CANNOT GET /{whatever i put after the dash}".
I will try doing the route for each component

Comment: @NehuenTupacCoveloDuran You *can* make it work without an explicit route definition for each file (that was just a hypothetical example; it's a terribly bad approach and you weren't actually supposed to do that) by removing all your route definitions (`routes.get(...)`) and replacing it with that one line of code I provided. It worked on my machine.

Comment: Im a really dumbass, haha i forgot that i change the folder name some hours ago and when i tried your code it was a bad path. Still, thank u man, its working now